# Can not get CSS Sticky footer to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, footer, sticky

Well, this is my first post here and really enjoying the site.

I have a very basic (ugly as sin) site I have started and for some reason, I can not get the CSS Sticky footer to work for FireFox.  IE works but FF shows it halfway up the page.

The URL is http://dev.aipoker.co.uk

I know I should be developing in FF and bug fixing in IE so I am guessing I might have actually made a mistake and somehow it works in IE but nowhere else.

Can anyone help put me out of my misery please?

Thanks, guys and gals.

Comment: Fx 3.0.x on WinXP looks almost the same as IE7 on this machine. Can you provide a picture or more detail about what you're trying to accomplish (link to functioning example would be nice too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [one](http://boagworld.com/dev/fixed-footers-without-javascript/), it works well on Firefox.

BTW, you should listen to Boagworld's podcast if you don't already. It's brilliant! :)

Cheers.

Comment: Looks like they've moved the article here: http://boagworld.com/dev/fixed-footers-without-javascript/

Answer (score 4):

I've had success with code like this:

```
footer { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%; 
  bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: It (always) sticks to the bottom, but overlays the actual container contents.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal changes I can see to do this would be:

- move footerSection inside of body
- set position absolute on both body and footerSection
- set bottom = 0px on footerSection

which ends up with something like this in your head:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #body, #footerSection { position: absolute; }
  #footerSection { bottom: 0px; }
</style>

<div id="body">
   ...
   <div id="footerSection">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **all you need to know** about css only sticky footers & sticky navs:

Stick to bottom of page

```
Position: absolute;
top:auto;
bottom: 0;
```

Stick to bottom of screen

```
Position: fixed;
top:auto;
bottom:0;
```

Any issues and it's probably due to where you placed your html code (don't make the footer a child element unless it's sticking to the content wrapper), or overlapping CSS.

You can apply the same technique to sticky navigation by flipping the auto & top. It'sis cross browser compatible (From memory from IE7 and above) including mobiles.