# Footer won't stick to the bottom..help?

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I've been reading a lot of questions and answers here and tried it over and over again but I can't get the footer to stick. Here is the link: http://guntherkoo.com/new/

The footer just doesn't want to stay at the bottom..but when I shrink the window size, it stays?

Please help!! 
Thank you!!

Comment: Try using this code: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159487/can-not-get-css-sticky-footer-to-work-what-am-i-doing-wrong/10016187#10016187

Check out the one entirely about css sticky footers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You footer is stuck to the bottom of `div#pageWrap`. Try moving the footer div outside of that #pageWrap div, so it sticks to the bottom of the `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: yes, you can use the "position:fixed;bottom:0px;" as mentioned by GregM but when the page is longer than the brower windows, the footer will hide your content. it is better to user a javascript solution, like this one : http://www.codicode.com/art/the_best_sticky_footer.aspx